# Transfer data to a one table from two databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

How can I create a table in mysql that can access by two databases
one is a court database and other one is police database
what i want is when court insert some records of suspects persons, that records should be accessible by police .but police are a different database.

hw i could do it. i'm a new-bee to programming and would love to have your help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have separate users there with permission restrictions. Use fully qualified names. For example `SELECT column_name FROM database_name.table_name` or `SELECT database_name.table_name.column_name`.

More info here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

If the two databases are on the same sewrver you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO
 database2.table2 (c1, c2, c3)

 SELECT
 c2, c4, MD5(c3) 
FROM
   database1.table1
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050998/copying-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-databases-are-different-and-table) too